# Parsing data in json using java

Tags: java, json

I have to parse the following data

```
{"ResultSet":{"Query":"microsec fin","Result":
[{"symbol":"MICROSE_a.NS","name": "MICROSEC FIN SERV LTD ","exch": "NSI","type": "S","exchDisp":"NSE","typeDisp":"Equity"},
   {"symbol":"MICROSEC.NS","name": "Microsec Fin Serv Ltd","exch": "NSI","type": "S","exchDisp":"NSE","typeDisp":"Equity"}]}}
```

The code i am using is

```
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(inputLine);
symbol=json.getJSONObject("ResultSet").getJSONArray("Result").getJSONObject(0).getString("symbol");
```

which returns MICROSE_a.NS. What i want to do is if there is an undersore in symbol then i want the next symbol to be taken. That is now i want symbol to actually hold MICROSEC.NS. How do i do this.

Comment: Simply reiterate through the JSON object and pick first item. If item has underscore, pick the next using a flag.

Comment: You'll have to check the current symbol for _ and then select the next symbol using the same statement. You could probably put this in a loop.

Comment: Could you please post some code as im a little confused right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or which is much simpler with your library:

```
JSONArray Result= json.getJSONObject("ResultSet").getJSONArray("Result");
for(int i = 0; i<Result.length(); i++){ 
    String symbol = Result.getJSONObject(i).getString("Symbol");
    if(!symbol.contains("_"))
          return symbol;
}
```